# Timer on a WPF Modal Dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am trying to launch a modal dialog from WPF MainWindow. The modal dialog contains two buttons "Install Now" and "Install Later". Once the MainWindow Launches the modal dialog, a timer starts from 30 seconds. It waits for user to click any one of the two buttons. If user does not clicks on any button within 30 seconds, the modal window is closed and MainWindow proceeds further. MainWindow was till now waiting for the modal window to close.

Here is the code from main window:

```
InstallNotify objInstallNotify = null;
                        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            Logger.WriteToLog("Displaying Notification Dialog");
                            objInstallNotify = new InstallNotify();
                            objInstallNotify.ShowDialog();

                        }));

if (objInstallNotify.ISPOSTPONECLICKED)
                            return;
```

The code in the InstallNotify is as follows:

```
public partial class InstallNotify : Window
{
    private static int totaltime = 30;
    //System.Threading.Timer dispatcherTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(dispatcherTimer_Tick1,null,1000,1000);
    private System.Timers.Timer objTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    private bool bPostponeBtnClicked = false;
    private bool bInstallNowBtnClicked = false;

    public bool ISPOSTPONECLICKED
    {
        get
        {
            return bPostponeBtnClicked;
        }
    }

    public bool ISINSTALLNOWCLICKED
    {
        get
        {
            return bInstallNowBtnClicked;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public InstallNotify()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void InstallNotifyLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Logger.WriteToLog("Launched dialog");
        this.objTimer.Interval = 1000; //1 sec
        this.objTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(TTTimer_Elapsed);
        this.objTimer.Start();
    }

    private void TTTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate()
        {
            TimeLeftInSecs.Content = totaltime.ToString();
            Logger.WriteToLog("Timer Count = " + totaltime);
        });
        totaltime--;
        if (totaltime < 0)
        {
            objTimer.Stop();
            if (this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                Logger.WriteToLog("Closing form Access - True");
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke((System.Action)delegate
                {
                    Logger.WriteToLog("Closing form Access - False");
                    this.Close();
                });
            }
        }

    }

    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeLeftInSecs.Content = totaltime.ToString();
        totaltime--;
        if (totaltime < 0)
        {
            //dispatcherTimer.Stop();
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This event handler is called when user clicks on the postpone button
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void PostponeBtnClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bPostponeBtnClicked = true;
        this.Close();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This event handler is called when user clicks on the Install Now button
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void InstallNowClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bInstallNowBtnClicked = true;
        this.Close();
    }

}
```

When I try to run this code, it works fine.
Now I call my executable through the windows task scheduler and lock my screen. This time it does not write the message "Displaying Notification Dialog" in the log file instead program fails with an exception:

> Details of exception are : The operation completed successfully
>   1:33:24 AM Thursday, October 13, 2016 : Stack Trace for the exception
>   is    at MS.Win32.SafeNativeMethods.ReleaseCapture()    at
>   System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()    at
>   MainWindow.<>c__DisplayClass27.b__24()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeDelegateCore()
>   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()

What is the problem here?

Comment: Task scheduler is only able to run command line applications while Windows is locked unfortunately.

Comment: I am able to call my application from task scheduler. It performs all the operations before calling the showdialog().

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific - any kind of interactive application won't run properly.

Comment: From what I could debug so far is that dispatcher operation on the non main thread does not fire when the screen is locked.